# How to extend predicate in lambda expression parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I would like to extend the expression parameter in my method to add my own filters. I am trying to do something like below, but the syntax is wrong:

```
public static IList<MyPage> DoSomething<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DataStore().GetPages().Where(p => p.PublishDate < DateTime.Now && predicate)
}
```

The compiler is complaining is complaining in Visual Studio 2012 with this error:

> Error 29  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type '`bool`'
>   and
>   '`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>`'

Would extending the predicate first be better then feed if back as `.Where(predicate)`? How would you do that?

Comment: I assume `GetPages()` returns an `IQueryale<T>`, right?

Comment: yes it does return IQueryable

Comment: sorry actually returning IList

Comment: Then why are you using `Expression` instead of `Func`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would extending the predicate first be better then feed if back as .Where(predicate)? How would you do that?

Yes, and exactly like that, if I understand what you are suggesting correctly. You can chain `.Where()` like this:

```
public static IList<MyPage> DoSomething<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DataStore().GetPages().Where(p => p.PublishDate < DateTime.Now).Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, in this specific case (ANDing predicates together), this is the best option. ORing would require something like `PredicateBuilder`.

Comment: The compiler error when I try that is: The best overloaded method match for 'PagesFacade.Where(System.Func<PageNode,bool>)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @svick For completeness, ORing is possible with `.Union()`, but when it gets translated to SQL, and the query gets complex enough, it could perform significantly worse than a real OR.

Comment: @TruMan1 Can you include the full message? Also, I now realise this is missing a `.ToList()` at the end (either that, or the return type of `DoSomething` needs a change), but that cannot cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: @TruMan1 That sounds like `GetPages()` doesn't return `IQueryable<T>` after all.

Comment: how embarassing.. you're right it returns an IList. Show I convert it to another type?